# Ошибка 6046: Невозможно сформировать возвращаемый тип импорта функции для функции хранилища "fn_diagramobjects"

Tags: sql, база-данных, visual-studio, entity-framework, импорт

Ошибка 6046: Невозможно сформировать возвращаемый тип импорта функции для функции хранилища "fn_diagramobjects"
При импорте или обновлении БД в визуалке. Импорт через модель ADO, проект WPF .NET Framework. EF 6.X.
Пробовал ставить разные версии визуалки и MS SQL SERVER.
Та же ошибка: не все таблицы импортируются. С другими БД также.
До этого ошибка фиксилась изменением пары свойств метода в файле EF.ttinclude
сейчас даже после подмены метода та же ошибка.

Ставил разные версии визуалки и SQL, переустанавливал EF в проекте, переписал БД.
Всё равно ошибка импорта. 12 таблиц вместо 17 + не все функции.

Answer (score 0):

[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1549267/Ошибка-6046-Невозможно-сформировать-возвращаемый-тип-импорта-функции-для-функци](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1549267/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-6046-%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8)
если не поможет то надо перебирать бд. так я и сделал: запихнул её в скрипт и убрал лишнее.в итоге все 17 таблиц закинулось в прогу

Comment: а зачем вы в ответе на вопрос привели ссылку на этот же вопрос?

Comment: чтобы ты спросил дружище, как видишь всё работает